# MySQL query to retrieve data based on date (sum of fields)

Tags: mysql

I'm new to MySQL so please be patient :)

I have a table where I would like to retrieve data based on date and do Sum

Here is my table

```
client    datescanned  problem   title
 abc      2019-02-02    12345a         High      xyz
 abc      2019-02-02    12345b         High      xyz 
 abc      2019-02-02    12345c         High      xyz
 abc      2019-02-02    12345d         Medium    xyz
 abc      2019-02-09    12345e         High      xyz 
 abc      2019-02-09    12345f         High      xyz
 abc      2019-02-09    12345g         Low       xyz
 abc      2019-02-09    12345h         Low       xyz
 abc      2019-02-09    12345j         Low       xyz
 abc      2019-02-16    12345x         High      xyz
 abc      2019-02-16    12345s         High      xyz
 abc      2019-02-16    12345w         High      xyz
 abc      2019-02-16    12345bs        Medium    xyz
```

My desired output would be

```
 client   datescanned  problem         High   Medium   Low 
 abc      2019-02-02    12345x          3       1       0
 abc      2019-02-09    12345s          2       0       3
 abc      2019-02-16    12345w          3       1       0
```

This is my code

```
select client,datescanned, problem, severity, 

         count(case when severity = 'High' then 1 end) as High,
         count(case when severity = 'Medium' then 1 end) as Medium,
         count(case when severity = 'Low' then 1 end) as Low

 from ssstest where client = "myuser"
 group by client,datescanned, problem
```

This will fetch all the numbers correctly, however I want to "sum" up High, Medium, Low per date.

Now I get..

```
client    datescanned  problem   severity      High  Medium  Low
 abc      2019-02-02    12345a      High        1      0      0
 abc      2019-02-02    12345b      High        1      0      0
 abc      2019-02-02    12345c      High        1      0      0 
 abc      2019-02-02    12345d      Medium      0      1      0 
 abc      2019-02-09    12345e      High        1      0      0 
 abc      2019-02-09    12345f      High        1      0      0 
 abc      2019-02-09    12345g      Low         0      0      1
 abc      2019-02-09    12345h      Low         0      0      1
 abc      2019-02-09    12345j      Low         0      0      1
 abc      2019-02-16    12345x      High        1      0      0
 abc      2019-02-16    12345s      High        1      0      0
 abc      2019-02-16    12345w      High        1      0      0
 abc      2019-02-16    12345bs     Medium      0      1      0
```

So basically, I just want to add up High, Medium, Low, group the same date together as one.

```
 client   datescanned  problem         High   Medium   Low 
 abc      2019-02-02    12345x          3       1       0
 abc      2019-02-09    12345s          2       0       3
 abc      2019-02-16    12345w          3       1       0
```

Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using `conditional aggregation`

```
select client,dateadded, computername, severity, 
       count(case when severity='High' then 1 end) as High,
       count(case when severity='Medium' then 1 end) as Medium,
       count(case when severity='Low' then 1 end) as Low,
from mytable where client =%CURRENT_USER_LOGIN%
group by client,dateadded, computername
```

Comment: > 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'from mytable where client like '%CURRENT_USER_LOGIN%'
group by client,dateadded, computerna' at line 5 :(

Comment: @enkiki, you can check now

Comment: Thanks for helping me Fa..  Still same error, i removed those 3 "count" lines to see if the error was from line #1,5,6 .. and I could see the table.  I suspect something in line #2,3,4 (count)... I ran the code directly in Navicat query and got error too (replaced the current_user_login with my actual username) .

Comment: code updated, your code is working by removing comma after High and Medium... only the Group by Date is missing... please see updated question/code.. Thx!

Comment: Working now, I removed the computername from Group :)

Answer (score 0):

Update(1):

In MySQL/MariaDB query the following doesn't much sense:

`=%CURRENT_USER_LOGIN%`

If substring you are searching for is `CURRENT_USER_LOGIN` then use
`like '%CURRENT_USER_LOGIN%'`

```sql
select client,dateadded, computername, severity, 
       count(case when severity='High' then 1 end) as High,
       count(case when severity='Medium' then 1 end) as Medium,
-- comma mark ',' before 'from' !!! produces error
       count(case when severity='Low' then 1 end) as Low,
from mytable where client =%CURRENT_USER_LOGIN%
group by client,dateadded, computername
```